# Any book on building a complete web service?

Tags: web-services

Is there any book that can guide me building secure webservices.

- Adding xsds to WSDL
- Adding WS security policies to WSDL

Any book that can describe how to put together a secure web service.

the language shouldn't matter, but it should explain the concepts and help the reader to put together all the pieces required for building a secure web service.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Spring "contract first" web service explanation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/tutorial.html) is excellent.